# Запрос в базу с агрегацией данных из несколько таблиц

Tags: mysql

Есть три таблицы типа persons,emails,phones.

persons

```
+----+-----------+-----+
| id | firstname | age |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 | Катя      |  12 |
|  2 | Лена      |  18 |
+----+-----------+-----+
```

email

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | email     | person_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | wer@sdf.ru|  1        |
|  2 |           |  2        |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

telephone

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | phone     | person_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 3423434324|  1        |
|  2 |           |  2        |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

Делаю запрос

```sql
SELECT * FROM persons p 
INNER JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
INNER JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id`
```

В таком случаи в таблицу на сайте попадает только Катя. Потому-что у нее есть и емейл и телефон. Как сделать мне запрос, чтобы в таблице была Лена?

Comment: А где здесь агрегация? По приведенным данным запрос должен отработать нормально, значит вы используете одну из агрегирующих функций, а значит надо указывать `GROUP BY some_field` в вашем случае по полю `person_id`. Ну либо данных в таблицах по Лене нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, Вам `INNER JOIN` нужно заменить на `LEFT JOIN`, чтобы выбирать даже тех людей, у которых в бд нет записей с телефоном или почтой.

Кстати, судя по приведенной схеме и описанной проблеме, у Вас все же нет записей в таблице `phones` или `emails` с `person_id=2`.

Скорее всего рабочий пример:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM persons p 
LEFT JOIN phones ph ON p.id = ph.person_id 
LEFT JOIN emails e ON p.id = e.person_id
```

Правда, сразу на будущее рекомендую все же не писать `SELECT *`, лучше всегда описывать нужный набор полей, например `select p.id, p.firstname, p.age, ph.phone, e.email`.